# Clojure: How to use re-seq to return a list of only alphanumeric chars as individual strings

Tags: clojure

I am trying to parse user input for a Clojure game. I would like to take any user-input string and turn each alphanumeric character into its own string, and then return a list of all these strings, ignoring whitespace and delimiters. The following illustrates what I am trying to accomplish:

```
(characters-as-strings "a   b")
; => ("a" "b")

(characters-as-strings "a   c,b")
; => ("a" "c" "b")
```

I have been trying `(defn characters-as-strings [userInput] re-seq #"[A-Z][a-z]" userInput)`, but this is only returning the actual string `"a   b"`. What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while the accepted answer solves the subclass of the problem, still it only handles latin letters, while the complete solution for handling alphanumerics including unicode letters could look something like this:

```
user> (re-seq #"\p{IsAlphabetic}|[0-9]" "a --- , ..b c ,de 1 22 ฆ й ζ")
;;=> ("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "1" "2" "2" "ฆ" "й" "ζ")
```

Answer (score 3):

You were really close. I only updated the regex:

```
(defn characters-as-strings [input]
  (re-seq #"[a-zA-Z]" input))

;; (characters-as-strings "a   b") ;; => ("a" "b") 
;; (characters-as-strings "a   c,b") ;; => ("a" "c" "b")
```

The only change was to put all the characters you wanted on the same class of the regular expression (eg. *"any lowercase or uppercase character"*). Your version was *"one uppercase character FOLLOWED by one lowercase character"*.

Comment: The OP asked to "turn each alphanumeric character into its own string", and not just alpha characters. If this was indeed what he meant, the pattern for that should actually be `#"[a-zA-Z0-9]"`. Also, a shorter alternative is `#"\w"` (that's the "word" class). @KhmerCoder

Comment: You're right, according to my original question, I did ask for alphanumeric. I had just forgotten to put the regex for 0-9 into the text of the question. Thanks for the pointer about the "word" class. I'll look into that. @amitr

Answer (score 1):

if you want you can use | in regular expressions.

```
(defn characters-as-strings [input-string]
  (filter #(pos? (count % )) (clojure.string/split input-string #"\s|,"))
  )

  (characters-as-strings "a   b") =>("a" "b")
  (characters-as-strings "a   c,b") => ("a" "c" "b")
```